# React hooks useInterval reset after button click

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have hook useInterval which download data every 10 seconds automaticaly, however I have also button which can manually download data in every moment. I'm struggling to restart interval timer when I click button. So basically if interval counts to 5, but I click button meantime, interval should restart and starts counting to 10 again before downloading data

```
const useInterval = (callback, delay) => {
    const savedCallback = useRef(callback);

    useEffect(() => {
        savedCallback.current = callback;
    }, [callback]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const tick = () => {
            savedCallback.current();
        }

        if (delay !== null) {
            const id = setInterval(tick, delay);
            return () => clearInterval(id);
        }
    }, [delay]);
};

export default useInterval;
```

APP PART:

```
useInterval(() => {
        getMessage();
      }, 10000)

const getMessage = async () => {
    setProcessing(true)
    try {
      const res = await fetch('url')
      const response = await res.json();
      setRecievedData(response)
    }
    catch (e) {
      console.log(e)
    }
    finally {
      setProcessing(false)
    }
  }

const getMessageManually = () => {
    getMessage()
    RESTART INTERVAL
  }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should add a reset function as returning a value from the hook.

I also fixed few issues and added an unmount handler:

```
// Usage
const resetInterval = useInterval(() => ..., DELAY);
resetInterval();
```

```
// Implementation
const useInterval = (callback, delay) => {
  const savedCallbackRef = useRef(callback);

  const intervalIdRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    savedCallback.current = callback;
  }, [callback]);

  // handle tick
  useEffect(() => {
    const tick = () => {
      savedCallback.current();
    };

    if (delay !== null) {
      intervalIdRef.current = setInterval(tick, delay);
    }

    const id = intervalIdRef.current;
    return () => {
      clearInterval(id);
    };
  }, [delay]);

  // handle unmount
  useEffect(() => {
    const id = intervalIdRef.current;
    return () => {
      clearInterval(id);
    };
  }, []);

  const resetInterval = useCallback(() => {
    clearInterval(intervalIdRef.current);
    intervalIdRef.current = setInterval(savedCallback.current, delay)
  }, [delay]);

  return resetInterval;
};
```

Comment: Reset actually stop but doesn't start new interval but I figured out how to do so thanks to your answer and now everything works fine. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

You can add a reset function in the hook and return that function. The reset function should clear the existing interval and start a new one.

Here is the code for the hook which can be reset and stopped.

```
const useInterval = (callback, delay) => {
  const savedCallback = useRef(callback);
  const intervalRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    savedCallback.current = callback;
  }, [callback]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (delay !== null) {
      const id = setInterval(savedCallback.current, delay);
      intervalRef.current = id;
      return () => clearInterval(id);
    }
  }, [delay]);

  useEffect(()=>{
    // clear interval on when component gets removed to avoid memory leaks
    return () => clearInterval(intervalRef.current);
  },[])

  const reset = useCallback(() => {
      if(intervalRef.current!==null){
        clearInterval(intervalRef.current);
        intervalRef.current = setInterval(savedCallback.current,delay)
      }
   });

   const stop = useCallback(() => {
      if(intervalRef.current!==null){
        clearInterval(intervalRef.current);
      }     
   })

  return {
    reset,
    stop
  };
};
    
// usage
const {reset,stop} = useInterval(()=>{},10000);
reset();
stop();
```

Comment: Just few mistakes: `clearInterval(intervalRef.current)` - You don't have the ref on unmount, `intervalRef!==null` is always truthy

Comment: @DennisVash Thanks. Corrected. But `clearInterval(intervalRef.current)` works. What's wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to remove the ref on the callback making the hook restart the count on every change to the callback

so updating the above solution

// Implementation
const useInterval = (callback, delay) => {

const intervalIdRef = useRef();

// handle tick
useEffect(() => {
const tick = () => {
callback();
};

```
if (delay !== null) {
  intervalIdRef.current = setInterval(tick, delay);
}

const id = intervalIdRef.current;
return () => {
  clearInterval(id);
};
```

}, [delay]);

// handle unmount
useEffect(() => {
const id = intervalIdRef.current;
return () => {
clearInterval(id);
};
}, []);
};

And then you can use it like this

```
const [counter, setCounter] = useState[0]
const onTimerFinish = useCallback(() => {
  setCounter(counter + 1)
  // setCounter will reset the interval
}, [counter])

useResetInterval(() => {
  onTimerFinish()
}, 5000)
```

Answer (score 0):

The hook is based on the `useEffect => returned cleanup function` React page cycle to establish and clear timers, which means that you can let this hook handle it by changing state, specifically the dependency `[delay]`, to induce it to clear and recreate.  Setting `delay` to `null` does cancel the timer, but how to restart?  One easy way is just to change it by one millisecond and use the hook as is:

```
const DEFAULT_DELAY = 5000
const [delay, setDelay] = useState(DEFAULT_DELAY)

function useInterval(callback, delay) {
    
    const savedCallback = useRef();

    // Remember the latest callback.
    useEffect(() => {
    savedCallback.current = callback;
    }, [callback]);

    // Set up the interval.
    useEffect(() => {
    function tick() {
        savedCallback.current();
    }
    if (delay !== null) {
        let id = setInterval(tick, delay);
        return () => clearInterval(id);
    }
    }, [delay]);
}

useInterval(yourFunction, delay)

return(
    <button onClick={(ev) => { setDelay(delay===DEFAULT_DELAY?DEFAULT_DELAY+1:DEFAULT_DELAY);  handleButtonPress(ev);  }}>click me</button> 
)
```