# Restart useInterval delay after button is clicked

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using [useInterval](https://www.npmjs.com/package/use-interval) in order to automatically pass pictures every 5 seconds, and I would like to know if there is a way to reset the delay when the "next" button is clicked. For instance, if I click the button after 3 seconds to pass to the second picture, then the third picture is passing to the next one after the remaining 2 seconds. The behavior that I would want is if I pass to the second picture by clicking on the button after, e.g. 3 seconds, the delay will restart to 5 seconds again.

This is a summary of my code:

```
const currentSlide = signal(0);
const intervalTime = 5000;

    function nextSlide() {
        if (currentSlide.value === slideLength-1) {
            return currentSlide.value = 0
        }
        else {
            return currentSlide.value++;
        }
    };

useInterval(() => { 
            nextSlide();
    }, intervalTime);
```

It is very similar to what I found in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66043252/react-hooks-useinterval-reset-after-button-click?rq=3), however, Jacki didn't post the solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Remember that setInterval has [clearInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/clearInterval) as counterpart.

Comment: Right, but for some reason it doesn't clear it after I click on the button. You can test this in this example https://codesandbox.io/s/ticker-liqo9?file=/src/index.js
You will notice that if you increase the delay to e.g. 5000, and hit the restart button after 3s, you will notice the counter changes in less than 5s.

Comment: you're not actually doing anything when reset gets clicked though. Yes, you call `setTick(0)`, but that's all that happens. What, in the code you wrote, makes you believe that it should have somehow triggered the function that you return in the deeply nested useEffect? (And please put that code in your post instead, so folks can meaningfully comment on it, after reducing it a little further to a [mcve])

Comment: Hey there, from my original post you will notice that I don't believe that it should have triggered anything, and what I am trying to find out is a way to reset/restart the delay when I click a button. I think, as stated by one of the answers below, the way to go is to create a dynamic delay that is passed to the useInterval hook.

Comment: not sure even that makes sense: just make the interval id itself a state value so you can use that? e.g. `[timer, setTimer] = setState(-1)` and a `const reset = () => { clearInterval(timer); setTimer(setInterval(..., ...)); }`? Why all the effects/callbacks/etc, that just makes things needlessly complicated?

Comment: Thanks a lot! You are totally right, make it simpler without all that effect/callback stuff did it. What I had to do was as your idea suggested to use the clearInterval at the beginning of my function, and that worked like a charm.

Comment: It's easy to forget that React is still "just JS", where you end up writing way too much code because you're trying to only use React constructs =)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
const currentSlide = signal(0);
const intervalTime = 5000;

function nextSlide() {
    if (currentSlide.value === slideLength-1) {
        return currentSlide.value = 0
    }
    else {
        return currentSlide.value++;
    }
    intervalTime = 5000; //to reset time after go next
};

useInterval(() => { 
      nextSlide();
}, intervalTime);
```

Comment: Tried this and it didn't work.

Comment: try make function to reset intervalTime and go next slide and link it with next button

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Answering..

> in this example(codesandbox.io/..) You will notice that if you increase the delay to e.g. 5000, and hit the restart button after 3s, you will notice the counter changes in less than 5s.

You need to add a new state variable in your `Ticker` to control the delay. You should modify the `useInterval` to accept a delay that can be changed dynamically. This will allow you to adjust the delay based on certain conditions. Next, you need to adjust the delay based on the `tick`. If `tick` is greater than **540** and less than **900**, you should set the delay example **5000**(or 5 seconds). You can do this inside a `useEffect` that depends on the `tick`. Lastly, you need to reset the `tick` and the delay example **1000**(or 1 second) when the warning or error message is clicked. You can do this inside the `reset` function.

Modified `Ticker`;

```
function Ticker({ onError }) {
 const [tick, setTick] = useState(0);
 const [delay, setDelay] = useState(1000);

 function reset() {
   setTick(0);
   setDelay(1000);
 }

 useEffect(() => {
   if (tick > 540 && tick < 900) {
     setDelay(5000);
   } else {
     setDelay(1000);
   }
 }, [tick]);

 useInterval(() => {
   console.log("useInterval");
   if (tick === -1) return;
   setTick(tick + 60);
 }, delay);

 if (tick >= 900) {
   onError();
 }

 return (
   <div>
     {tick > 540 && (
       <TickerAlert color="orange" message="Warning!" onClick={reset} />
     )}
     <b>{tick}</b>
   </div>
 );
}
```